# The getter 'totalCartPrice' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: totalCartPrice

Tags: flutter

**The app itself works well. The product is added to the cart, but when you go to the cart page, this error appears. Maybe someone came across. I looked at similar errors, but my solution did not help.**
*The getter 'totalCartPrice' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: totalCartPrice*

enter code here

```
                import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
                import 'package:food_course/scr/helpers/order.dart';
                import 'package:food_course/scr/helpers/style.dart';
                import 'package:food_course/scr/models/cart_item.dart';
                import 'package:food_course/scr/models/products.dart';
                import 'package:food_course/scr/providers/app.dart';
                import 'package:food_course/scr/providers/user.dart';
                import 'package:food_course/scr/widgets/custom_text.dart';
                import 'package:food_course/scr/widgets/loading.dart';
                import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
                import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';
                
                class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
                  @override
                  _CartScreenState createState() => _CartScreenState();
                }
                
                class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
                  final _key = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
                  OrderServices _orderServices = OrderServices();
                
                  @override
                  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                    final user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
                    final app = Provider.of<AppProvider>(context);
                
                
                
                    return Scaffold(
                      key: _key,
                      appBar: AppBar(
                        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: black),
                        backgroundColor: white,
                        elevation: 0.0,
                        title: CustomText(text: "Shopping Cart"),
                        leading: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            }),
                      ),
                      backgroundColor: white,
                      body: app.isLoading ? Loading() : ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: user.userModel.cart.length,
                          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 120,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                    color: white,
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          color: red.withOpacity(0.2),
                                          offset: Offset(3, 2),
                                          blurRadius: 30)
                                    ]),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    ClipRRect(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                                        topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                                      ),
                                      child: Image.network(
                                        user.userModel.cart[index].image,
                                        height: 120,
                                        width: 140,
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 10,
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          RichText(
                                            text: TextSpan(children: [
                                              TextSpan(
                                                  text: user.userModel.cart[index].name+ "\n",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: black,
                                                      fontSize: 20,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                                              TextSpan(
                                                  text: "\$${user.userModel.cart[index].price / 100} \n\n",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: black,
                                                      fontSize: 18,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300)),
                                              TextSpan(
                                                  text: "Quantity: ",
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: grey,
                                                      fontSize: 16,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                                              TextSpan(
                                                  text: user.userModel.cart[index].quantity.toString(),
                                                  style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: primary,
                                                      fontSize: 16,
                                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                                            ]),
                                          ),
                                          IconButton(
                                              icon: Icon(
                                                Icons.delete,
                                                color: red,
                                              ),
                                              onPressed: ()async{
                                                app.changeLoading();
                                                bool value = await user.removeFromCart(cartItem: user.userModel.cart[index]);
                                                if(value){
                                                  user.reloadUserModel();
                                                  print("Item added to cart");
                                                  _key.currentState.showSnackBar(
                                                      SnackBar(content: Text("Removed from Cart!"))
                                                  );
                                                  app.changeLoading();
                                                  return;
                                                }else{
                                                  print("ITEM WAS NOT REMOVED");
                                                  app.changeLoading();
                                                }
                                              })
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }),
                      bottomNavigationBar: Container(
                        height: 70,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              RichText(
                                text: TextSpan(children: [
                                  TextSpan(
                                      text: "Total: ",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: grey,
                                          fontSize: 22,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400)),
                                  TextSpan(
                                      text: " \$${user.userModel.totalCartPrice / 100}",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: primary,
                                          fontSize: 22,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                                ]),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20), color: primary),
                                child: FlatButton(
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if(user.userModel.totalCartPrice == 0){
                                        showDialog(
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                              return Dialog(
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                    BorderRadius.circular(20.0)), //this right here
                                                child: Container(
                                                  height: 200,
                                                  child: Padding(
                                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                                    child: Column(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                      children: [
                                                        Row(
                                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                          children: <Widget>[
                                                            Text('Your cart is emty', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                                                          ],
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              );
                                            });
                                        return;
                                      }
                                      showDialog(
                                          context: context,
                                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                            return Dialog(
                                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(20.0)), //this right here
                                              child: Container(
                                                height: 200,
                                                child: Padding(
                                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                                                  child: Column(
                                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                                    children: [
                                                      Text('You will be charged \$${user.userModel.totalCartPrice / 100} upon delivery!', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                
                                                      SizedBox(
                                                        width: 320.0,
                                                        child: RaisedButton(
                                                          onPressed: () async{
                                                            var uuid = Uuid();
                                                            String id = uuid.v4();
                                                            _orderServices.createOrder(
                                                              userId: user.user.uid,
                                                              id: id,
                                                              description: "Some random description",
                                                              status: "complete",
                                                              totalPrice: user.userModel.totalCartPrice,
                                                              cart: user.userModel.cart
                                                            );
                                                            for(CartItemModel cartItem in user.userModel.cart){
                                                              bool value = await user.removeFromCart(cartItem: cartItem);
                                                              if(value){
                                                                user.reloadUserModel();
                                                                print("Item added to cart");
                                                                _key.currentState.showSnackBar(
                                                                    SnackBar(content: Text("Removed from Cart!"))
                                                                );
                                                              }else{
                                                                print("ITEM WAS NOT REMOVED");
                                                              }
                                                            }
                                                            _key.currentState.showSnackBar(
                                                                SnackBar(content: Text("Order created!"))
                                                            );
                                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                
                                                          },
                                                          child: Text(
                                                            "Accept",
                                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                                          ),
                                                          color: const Color(0xFF1BC0C5),
                                                        ),
                                                      ),
                                                      SizedBox(
                                                        width: 320.0,
                                                        child: RaisedButton(
                                                          onPressed: () {
                                                            Navigator.pop(context);
                                                          },
                                                          child: Text(
                                                            "Reject",
                                                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                                          ),
                                                          color: red
                                                        ),
                                                      )
                
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          });
                                    },
                                    child: CustomText(
                                      text: "Check out",
                                      size: 20,
                                      color: white,
                                      weight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    )),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }
          


                    USER.dart

import 'dart:async';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/helpers/order.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/helpers/user.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/models/cart_item.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/models/order.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/models/products.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/models/user.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';


enum Status{Uninitialized, Authenticated, Authenticating, Unauthenticated}

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  FirebaseAuth _auth;
  FirebaseUser _user;
  Status _status = Status.Uninitialized;
  Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  UserServices _userServicse = UserServices();
  OrderServices _orderServices = OrderServices();
  UserModel _userModel;

//  getter
  UserModel get userModel => _userModel;
  Status get status => _status;
  FirebaseUser get user => _user;

  // public variables
  List<OrderModel> orders = [];

  final formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController name = TextEditingController();


  UserProvider.initialize(): _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance{
    _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(_onStateChanged);
  }

  Future<bool> signIn()async{
    try{
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();
      await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.text.trim(), password: password.text.trim());
      return true;
    }catch(e){
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      print(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }


  Future<bool> signUp()async{
    try{
      _status = Status.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();
      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email.text.trim(), password: password.text.trim()).then((result){
        _firestore.collection('users').document(result.user.uid).setData({
          'name':name.text,
          'email':email.text,
          'uid':result.user.uid,
          "likedFood": [],
          "likedRestaurants": []
        });
      });
      return true;
    }catch(e){
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();
      print(e.toString());
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future signOut()async{
    _auth.signOut();
    _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();
    return Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  }

  void clearController(){
    name.text = "";
    password.text = "";
    email.text = "";
  }

  Future<void> reloadUserModel()async{
    _userModel = await _userServicse.getUserById(user.uid);
    notifyListeners();
  }


  Future<void> _onStateChanged(FirebaseUser firebaseUser) async{
    if(firebaseUser == null){
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    }else{
      _user = firebaseUser;
      _status = Status.Authenticated;
      _userModel = await _userServicse.getUserById(user.uid);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> addToCard({ProductModel product, int quantity})async{
    print("THE PRODUC IS: ${product.toString()}");
    print("THE qty IS: ${quantity.toString()}");

    try{
      var uuid = Uuid();
      String cartItemId = uuid.v4();
      List cart = _userModel.cart;
//      bool itemExists = false;
      Map cartItem ={
        "id": cartItemId,
        "name": product.name,
        "image": product.image,
        "restaurantId": product.restaurantId,
        "totalRestaurantSale": product.price * quantity,
        "productId": product.id,
        "price": product.price,
        "quantity": quantity
      };

        CartItemModel item = CartItemModel.fromMap(cartItem);
//      if(!itemExists){
        print("CART ITEMS ARE: ${cart.toString()}");
        _userServicse.addToCart(userId: _user.uid, cartItem: item);
//      }



      return true;
    }catch(e){
      print("THE ERROR ${e.toString()}");
      return false;
    }

  }

  getOrders()async{
    orders = await _orderServices.getUserOrders(userId: _user.uid);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<bool> removeFromCart({CartItemModel cartItem})async{
    print("THE PRODUC IS: ${cartItem.toString()}");

    try{
      _userServicse.removeFromCart(userId: _user.uid, cartItem: cartItem);
      return true;
    }catch(e){
      print("THE ERROR ${e.toString()}");
      return false;
    }

  }
}

            main.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/providers/app.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/providers/category.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/providers/product.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/providers/restaurant.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/providers/user.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/screens/home.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/screens/login.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/screens/splash.dart';
import 'package:food_course/scr/widgets/loading.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: AppProvider()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: UserProvider.initialize()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: CategoryProvider.initialize()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: RestaurantProvider.initialize()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: ProductProvider.initialize()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Food App',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.red,
          ),
          home: ScreensController())));
}

class ScreensController extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final auth = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context);
    switch (auth.status) {
      case Status.Uninitialized:
        return Splash();
      case Status.Unauthenticated:
      case Status.Authenticating:
        return LoginScreen();
      case Status.Authenticated:
        return Home();
      default:
        return LoginScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code from your main.dart and the UserProvider files? Looking at this CartScreen code, the error seems to be indicating that the object "user.userModel" is null, which suggests the UserProvider might not be configured correctly. If I can see where your setting up the UserProvider, which I'm guessing is in main.dart, then maybe we can find why the Provider value is NULL.

Comment: @RoboBear added code user.dart and main.dart